# TurtleBot3 namespace issues (ROS1 Melodic)

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to implement some code that works with multiple turtlebot3s in a gazebo simulation onto a real robot.
The problem I am having is trying to create namespaces for each robot from a launch file. Currently just using the default turtlebot3 files to debug.

Following the instruction on [this tutorial](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/applications/#load-multiple-turtlebot3s) and writing this command on the robot:

```
ROS_NAMESPACE=Bot1 roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch multi_robot_name:="Bot1" set_lidar_frame_id:="Bot1/base_scan"
```

I get a nice output using `rostopic list`:

```
/Bot1/battery_state
/Bot1/cmd_vel
/Bot1/cmd_vel_rc100
/Bot1/diagnostics
/Bot1/firmware_version
/Bot1/imu
/Bot1/joint_states
/Bot1/magnetic_field
/Bot1/motor_power
/Bot1/odom
/Bot1/reset
/Bot1/rpms
/Bot1/scan
/Bot1/sensor_state
/Bot1/sound
/Bot1/version_info
/diagnostics
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
```

But when I try to write this to work in a launch file, as so:

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_robot.launch">
    <arg name="multi_robot_name" value="Bot1"/>
    <arg name="set_lidar_frame_id" value="Bot1/base_scan"/>
  </include>
</launch>
```

I get the same outputs but without a namespace.

```
/battery_state
/cmd_vel
/cmd_vel_rc100
/diagnostics
/firmware_version
/imu
/joint_states
/magnetic_field
/motor_power
/odom
/reset
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/rpms
/scan
/sensor_state
/sound
/tf
/version_info
```

But if I run `rostopic echo /odom`, the `frame_id` and `child_frame_id` are `"Bot1/odom"` and `"Bot1/base_footprint"` respectively.
So the namespace works, just not correctly?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392511/turtlebot3-namespace-issues-(ros1-melodic)/) by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2021-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those are not equivalent launch files, because you have not implemented the `ROS_NAMESPACE=Bot1` part in the launch file. You want to look up how the `<group ns="Bot1">` tag is used to modify the ros-node and topic names.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1